# Can i install OpenEdX platform in VMware Workstation?

Tags: vagrant, vmware, vmware-workstation, openedx

I think my question is clear from the Subject title

I had some problems while installing OpenEdX on VirtualBox so, i was thinking if i can install it using VMware Workstation.

Can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install it!

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2073803

This link should explain you how to do it.

Comment: The problem is when i do a `vagrant up` it goes automaticlly to virtualbox and run the virtual machine on it.

Comment: Why don't you uninstall Virtual Box? Because, you don't needVM ware and Virtualbox at the same time, one of them is enough, right?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work :( it's keeps freezing in 'vagrant up'

Comment: Then I don't know what to do anymore, sorry :(

Comment: it's ok, i'll try to find another solution, thank you for your effort !

Comment: No problem, hope you'll find a solution. And happy coding :D

Comment: Try installing using docker (devstack) or ansible (native) instead of vagrant.